# Regular expressions: How do I find a sub-string that is between two regular expression matches?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

Let's say I have a string like:

```
data = 'MESSAGE: Hello world!END OF MESSAGE'
```

And I want to get the string between `'MESSAGE: '` and the next capitalized word. There are never any fully capitalized words in the message.

I tried to get this by using this regular expression in `re.search`:

```
re.search('MESSAGE: (.*)([A-Z]{2,})', data).group(1)
```

Here I would like it to output `'Hello world!'`- but it always returns the wrong result. It is very easy in regular expressions for one to find a sub-string that occurs between two other strings, but how do you find a substring between strings that are matches for a regular expression. I have tried making it a raw string but that didn't seem to work.

I hope I am expressing myself well- I have extensive experience in Python but am new to regular expressions. If possible, I would like an explanation along with an example of how to make my specific example code work. Any helpful posts are greatly appreciated.

BTW, I am using Python 3.3.

Comment: I don't understand this: "how do you find a substring between strings that are matches for a regular expression?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't work but for the opposite reason:

```
re.search('MESSAGE: (.*)([A-Z]{2,})', data).group(1)
```

would match

```
'Hello world!END OF MESSA'
```

because `(.*)` is "greedy", i.e. it matches the most that will allow the rest (two uppercase chars) to match. You need to use a non-greedy quantifier with

```
re.search('MESSAGE: (.*?)([A-Z]{2,})', data).group(1)
```

that correctly matches

```
'Hello world!'
```

Answer (score 2):

One little question mark:

```
re.search('MESSAGE: (.*?)([A-Z]{2,})', data).group(1)
Out[91]: 'Hello world!'
```

if you make the first capturing group lazy, it won't consume anything after the exclamation point.

Answer (score 2):

You need your .* to be non-greedy (see the first `?`) which means that it stops matching at the point where the next item could match, and you need the second group to be non-capturing (see the `?:`).

```
import re 
data = 'MESSAGE: Hello world!END OF MESSAGE'    
regex = r'MESSAGE: (.*?)(?:[A-Z]{2,})'
re.search(regex, data).group(1)
```

Returns:

```
'Hello world!'
```

Alternatively, you could use this:

```
regex = r'MESSAGE: (.*?)[A-Z]{2,}'
```

To break this down (I'll include the search line with the VERBOSE flag:):

```
regex = r'''
         MESSAGE:\s    # first part, \s for the space (matches whitespace)
         (.*?)         # non-greedy, anything but a newline
         (?:[A-Z]{2,}) # a secondary group, but non-capturing,
                       #  good for alternatives separated by a pipe, |
         '''
re.search(regex, data, re.VERBOSE).group(1)
```

Comment: Why did you make the second group non-capturing?

Comment: He wants to return the first group and not the second.

Comment: Then.. just don't make it a group at all?  Personally I assumed he had a reason for that group so I left it in.